How to adjust internal padding used by MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
Consider this layout:

XML layout:
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
                        app:ccp_contentColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:ccp_defaultNameCode="ID" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/phonenumber"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/phone_number"
                        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

How to adjust the MaterialAutoCOmpleteTextView's internal padding, so the text "ID +62" and "9080706050" are on the same level?
